# No puedo agregar un registro a mi base de datos, marca error PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin, prepared-statements

Estoy intentando agregar datos a una base de datos mediante un botón pero al momento de ingresar los datos me arroja un error en la parte de Prepared Statement y mi sentencia SQL la he probado en mi servidor local (phpmyadmin) y ha funcionado a la perfección, y no he podido avanzar en mi proyecto por ese error.

Les dejo parte de mi código:

**Esto es al momento de presionar el botón de agregar a la base de datos**

```
    conexionBD cc = new conexionBD();
    Connection cn=cc.conectar;
    String sql="";

    if(rbnHerraOfi.isSelected())
        tip=rbnHerraOfi.getText();
    else
        tip=rbnArtPape.getText();
    sql="INSERT INTO productos (Articulo,Precio_compra,Precio_venta,Stock_min,TipoArticulo,Cantidad) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    try {
         PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
         pst.setString(1,txt_NombrePro.getText());
         pst.setDouble(2,Double.parseDouble(txtPrecioCompraPro.getText()));
         pst.setDouble(3,Double.parseDouble(txtPrecioVentaPro.getText()));
         pst.setInt(4,Integer.parseInt(txtStockMinimo.getText()));
         pst.setString(5,tip);
         pst.setInt(6,Integer.parseInt(txtCantidadPro.getText()));

         int n=pst.executeUpdate();
         if(n>=0){
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Registros Guardados con Exito");
              limpiar();
         }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,""+ex);

    }
        `
```

**Y esto es lo que tengo en mi clase de conexión**

```
public class conexionBD {
    Connection conectar=null;

    public Connection conectar() {

        try {
            Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
            conectar=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/papeleria","root","");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conectado correctamente");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al conectarse a la base de datos"+e);
        }
        return conectar;
    }
}
```

Este es el error que recibo:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at pepeleria2.Admin2.btnGuardarProActionPerformed(Admin2.java:650)

La línea 650 es justamente donde esta el `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: por favor, aclara que error estas recibiendo

Comment: Usa el boton [edit] y agrega la informacion a la pregunta

Comment: Lo siento soy nuevo :)

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67564/discussion-on-question-by-sebastian-no-puedo-agregar-un-registro-a-mi-base-de-da).

Comment: Si el error es en esa línea, PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(sql);, tiene que ser que con es null, revísalo.

Answer (score -1):

La sentencia `String sql="";` crea una instrucción *SQL* vacía para, según el bucle *if*, iniciarla o no según si `rbnHerraOfi.isSelected()` o no. La sentencia *if* funciona perfectamente a pesar de no llevar el código interior en corchetes porque solo contiene una sentencia. Pero la sentencia *else* contiene exactamente 2 líneas. Se desaconseja no introducir corchetes, porque como en tu caso, si excedes el número de sentencias mayor que 1, sólo ejecutará la primera. Añade corchetes a esa sentencia *if* de esta manera:

```
if(rbnHerraOfi.isSelected()) {
        tip=rbnHerraOfi.getText();
   } else {
        tip=rbnArtPape.getText();
        sql="INSERT INTO productos (Articulo,Precio_compra,Precio_venta,Stock_min,TipoArticulo,Cantidad) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
   }
```

Comment: Lo siento amigo eso no soluciona el erro, sigue marcando en la linea del PreparedStatement, pero gracias

Comment: Victor, mas alla de que tu apreciacion sobre los corchetes sea correcta (siempre es mejor ponerlos), que tendria que ver con el error? si lo haces de esta forma, sql pasaria a veces totaltmente vacio y nadie lo llenaria.

Comment: La relación es que permite pasar la sentencia sql vacía a la declaración de la línea 650, lo mismo sucede si rbnHerraOfi no es seleccionado. Pero... es evidente que falta información para hablar con seguridad

Comment: @gbianchi Si no pones corchetes a la sentencia solo ejecuta la primera instrucción que contenga aunque contenga más. Es decir, ese código siempre pasa una sentencia sql vacía